# How can I get German umlauts with fs.readFileSync?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, csv, papaparse

I want to try to read my csv file and convert it so that I have the german umlauts back in. How can I convert this?

my code:

```
export const convertCSV = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const file = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'files', 'csv.csv'), "utf-8");
    let csvData: any = [];
    papa.parse(file, {
        dynamicTyping: true,
        skipEmptyLines: true,
        step: function (result) {
            csvData.push(result.data)
        },
        complete: function (results, file) {
            //console.log('Complete', results.data, 'records.');
        }
    })
    res.status(200).send(csvData)
}
```

With this code I always get these characters � if I have an umlaut. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Node are you running? The suggested string to pass for UTF-8 encoding in Node.js is `"utf8"`, without the dash, however `"utf-8"` has been a valid alias for [at least 5 years now](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blame/46f202690b83bda6ba4b49291a8fd107f7ef1496/lib/buffer.js#L413). It may not have been [in older releases](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node/blob/d1745175c26f503c81a24600cd8b97e2ec966bbc/doc/api/buffer.markdown).